# Calculating number of bits in a cache

Tags: caching, computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

> *Preface*: There are many different design patterns that are important to cache's overall performance. Below are listed parameters for
> different direct-mapped cache designs.
>
> - Cache data size: 32 kib
> - Cache block Size: 2 words
> - Cache access time: 1-cycle
>
> *Question*: Calculate the number of bits required for the cache listed above, assuming a 32-bit address. Given that total size, find the
> total size of the closest direct-mapped cache with 16-word blocks of
> equal size or greater. Explain why the second cache, despite its
> larger data size, might provide slower performance that the first
> cache.

*Here's the formula*:
Number of bits in a cache 2^n X (block size + tag size + valid field size)

*Here's what I got*:  `65536(1+14X(32X2)`..
is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using: `(2^index bits) * (valid bits + tag bits + (data bits * 2^offset bits))`

for the first one i get:

```
total bits = 2^15 (1+14+(32*2^1)) = 2588672 bits
```

for the cache with 16 word blocks i get:

```
total bits = 2^13(1 +13+(32*2^4)) = 4308992
```

the next smallest cache with **16 word blocks and a 32 bit address works out to be 2158592 bits**, smaller than the first cache.

Comment: How did you find `2^15 blocks` on the first part? Since the cache data size is `32KiB` and there is `2 words/block`, `32 * 2^10 bytes / 8 bytes` results in `2^12 blocks`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm stuck on the same problem too but I have the answer to the first part.

To calculate the total number of bits required

1. You need to convert the KB to words and get the index bits.
2. Use the answer from part 1 to get your tag bits.
3. Plug them into this formula.

   ```
   (2^(index bits)) * ((tag bits)+(valid bits)+(data size))
   ```

**Hint**: data size is 64 bits in this case and valid bit is 1. So just find the index and tag bits.

And I don't think your answer is right. I didn't check but I can see you are multiplying 1+14 and (32x2) instead of adding them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the formula you were using is correct. According to my textbook "Computer Organization and Design The Hardware, 5th edition", the total number of bits in a direct-mapped cache is:

```
2^indext bits * (block size + tag size + valid field size).
```

- block size was given by the question: 2 words = 32 bits
- tag size: 32 - offset in bits - index in bits
- valid field size is usually 1 valid bit

Comment: The question doesn't specify the word size, but given that address-size is 32-bit, a good guess would be word-size = 32-bit.  (So a pointer is 1 word, like a typical 32-bit RISC).  More likely than the 16-bit word size you're assuming.  A better question would have specified the word size instead of leaving answerers to guess.  Perhaps it was implied by some context the OP left out.